# Replace digits using sed

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed, pattern-matching

I want all digits after a equal sign in a given string to be replaced with the text 'NULL'. I am new to using sed. How do I get the desired output using sed?

Example 1:

```
Input: /getProduct?productId=1234&quanity=4  
Output: /getProduct?productId=NULL&quantity=NULL
```

Example 2:

```
Input: /getCustomers?customerId=432  
Output: /getCustomers?customerId=NULL
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried? How close have you come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed -r 's/(=)([0-9]+)/\1NULL/g' inputfile.txt` on inputfile:

```
/getProduct?productId=1234&quanity=4
/getCustomers?customerId=432
/getCustomers3?customerId=432
```

we get:

```
/getProduct?productId=NULL&quanity=NULL
/getCustomers?customerId=NULL
/getCustomers3?customerId=NULL
```

Only digits appearing after the equal sign are changed.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
echo "/getProduct?productId=1234&quanity=4" | sed -E 's/[0-9]+/NULL/g'
```

- [0-9]+: one or more digits
- g: applies to all matches